# How can I run a script on every specific number of frames?

Tags: rendering, keyframes

Here's the script for running a specific command for every frame change.

```
import bpy

def run_script(scene):
    print("Hello World")

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(run_script)
```

I want to make it happen lets say 20 frames, what should I do?

Comment: `if scene.frame_current < 20:` ?

Comment: I'm seeking like a command like "every.x.frame"
So it should be executing the command on every x frames.
Lets say x=5, so it'll be executed on frames 5-10-15-20...

Comment: then `if scene.frame_current % x == 0:` cf modulo https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: Can u give me an example for every 5 frames? I mean x will be %500?

Comment: `%` (modulo) operator evaluates to 0 if and only if the number on the left is a multiple of the number on the right. This means `a % 5` will amount to 0 every time `a` is a multiple of 5 for instance. If you can't figure it out I'll write it as an answer in a bit :)

Comment: Ty man for the explaination, though I couldn't make it work unfortunately.
So I've been trying to run this script every 24 frames, instead of every frame:

import bpy

def run_script(scene):
    bpy.ops.spectrum_palette.palette_gen()
    bpy.ops.scene.pl_studio_next()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(run_script)

Though when I add the if scene.frame_current % x == 0, it's not working at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% (modulo) operator evaluates to 0 if the number on the left is a multiple of the number on the right. This means a % 5 will amount to 0 every time a is a multiple of 5.

```
import bpy
counter = 24

def run_script(scene):
    if scene.frame_current % counter == 0:
        print(f"{scene.frame_current} is a multiple of {counter} !")

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(run_script)
```

You'll note 0 % 24 is 0 so if you don't want to fire the script on frame 0 you can use:

`if scene.frame_current > 0 and scene.frame_current % counter == 0:`